# How to correctly access a non-constant index in an LLVM array?

Tags: arrays, llvm, llvm-ir, instructions

I've been trying to tackle arrays in LLVM, but I am not able to access elements at a non-constant index. Constant indexing works correctly. When I run my program, it just immediately exits. In my specific example, I am trying to use a for loop to set the elements for 0 to 5 to their respective value. This is what LLVM outputs (with optimizations disabled):

```
Read function definition:define double @main() {
entry:
  %i = alloca double, align 8
  %test = alloca [100 x double]*, align 8
  store double 0.000000e+00, [100 x double]* %test, align 8
  store double 0.000000e+00, double %i, align 8
  br label %loop

loop:                                             ; preds = %latch, %entry
  %i1 = phi double [ 0.000000e+00, %entry ], [ %nextvar, %latch ]
  %i2 = load double, double %i, align 8
  %cmptmp = fcmp ult double %i2, 5.000000e+00
  %booltmp = uitofp i1 %cmptmp to double
  %loopcond = fcmp one double %booltmp, 0.000000e+00
  br i1 %loopcond, label %body, label %afterloop

body:                                             ; preds = %loop
  %i3 = load double, double %i, align 8
  %casttmp = fptosi double %i3 to i32
  %reftmp = getelementptr [100 x double], [100 x double]* %test, i32 0, i32 %casttmp
  store double 5.000000e+00, double* %reftmp, align 8
  br label %latch

latch:                                            ; preds = %body
  %i4 = load double, double %i, align 8
  %nextvar = fadd double %i4, 1.000000e+00
  store double %nextvar, double %i, align 8
  br label %loop

afterloop:                                        ; preds = %loop
  %reftmp5 = getelementptr [100 x double], [100 x double]* %test, i32 0, i32 0
  %loadtmp = load double, double* %reftmp5, align 8
  %calltmp = call double @print(double %loadtmp)
  ret double %calltmp
}
```

The most important block in which the array access happens, is body. This is how the code looks, to help with what's supposed to happen:

```
fun main() {
    mut test: number[100]
    for(i = 0, i < 5) {
        test[i] = 5
    }
    print(test[0])
}
```

Print is an external function that is 100% tested and it works correctly.
Print statements before the allocation don't seem to run either. If anyone notices anything wrong, it would be great!
PS: in my language, all numbers are doubles, so i is a double too, that's why I'm casting it to an integer.

Edit: I compiled the same code using clang and c++, and it gave the following llvm output:

```
define dso_local noundef i32 @main() #0 !dbg !207 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = alloca [100 x double], align 16
  %3 = alloca double, align 8
  store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4
  call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata [100 x double]* %2, metadata !210, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !215
  call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata double* %3, metadata !216, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !218
  store double 0.000000e+00, double* %3, align 8, !dbg !218
  br label %4, !dbg !219

4:                                                ; preds = %13, %0
  %5 = load double, double* %3, align 8, !dbg !220
  %6 = fcmp olt double %5, 5.000000e+00, !dbg !222
  br i1 %6, label %7, label %16, !dbg !223

7:                                                ; preds = %4
  %8 = load double, double* %3, align 8, !dbg !224
  %9 = load double, double* %3, align 8, !dbg !226
  %10 = fptosi double %9 to i32, !dbg !226
  %11 = sext i32 %10 to i64, !dbg !227
  %12 = getelementptr inbounds [100 x double], [100 x double]* %2, i64 0, i64 %11, !dbg !227
  store double %8, double* %12, align 8, !dbg !228
  br label %13, !dbg !229

13:                                               ; preds = %7
  %14 = load double, double* %3, align 8, !dbg !230
  %15 = fadd double %14, 1.000000e+00, !dbg !230
  store double %15, double* %3, align 8, !dbg !230
  br label %4, !dbg !231, !llvm.loop !232

16:                                               ; preds = %4
  %17 = getelementptr inbounds [100 x double], [100 x double]* %2, i64 0, i64 2, !dbg !235
  %18 = load double, double* %17, align 16, !dbg !235
  %19 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* noundef getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8], [3 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0), double noundef %18), !dbg !236
  %20 = load i32, i32* %1, align 4, !dbg !237
  ret i32 %20, !dbg !237
}
```

Which looks almost identical to what I have. I don't understand, why wouldn't this work...

Edit2: I've changed the base type of the array to char - i8, and then all of this works. I'm confused. I wonder if it has to do with the alignment? On clang-llvm, it's 16, at me, it's 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
store double 0.000000e+00, [100 x double]* %test, align 8
```

This looks ill-typed. `%test` has the type `[100 x double]**`, not `[100 x double]*` (`alloca T` will give you a pointer of type `T*`) and, in any case, to store a single double you should have a pointer of type `double*`.

As a piece of advice: If you're using the API, you should be calling `verifyModule` on your module when you're finished creating it. It will tell you when your code is ill-formed (and if you're generating the code as text and then compiling with `llc`, it should tell you the same) and will allow you to catch problems like this right away.

Comment: Thank you! This nudged me in the right direction. I forgot that I returned the type as a pointer to an array, not just array. So now the type of my array is what it should be. But now it doesn't let me create a GEP call, because it says that the value should be a pointer. But my value is an array. Do you know how I could create a pointer from my array?

Comment: @CodeForFun I'm not sure I understand your situation. If you changed the `alloca` to allocate an array (instead of a pointer to an array), the type of `%test` should now be `[100 x double]*` and you can indeed use GEP to get a pointer to one of its arguments. If that's what you have and it's not working, please post your current code and the exact error message.

Comment: As I was writing my reply, I noticed that I had a `alloca->mutateType(type);` instruction when creating the alloca (I had problems with types, that's why it was stuck there), and commenting that out fixed the array. So the problem is closed, thank you a lot for helping me. Have a great day!

Comment: Absolutely never use `mutateType`. The whole of LLVM is written in such a way as to assume that the Type of a Value is immutable from the moment a Value is created, but this method was added as a performance hack for the bitcode file parser. I opposed its addition on the grounds that people might think it's OK to use. It isn't.

Comment: Beyond using `verifyModule`, also ensure that LLVM's assertions are enabled. LLVM uses assertions extensively and nearly-all of them include plain text about the failure. With assertions disabled, LLVM will freely execute undefined behaviour when the API is misused.